# how to make a particular node selected and other unselected GOJS

Tags: gojs

there are two GOJS diagram if i click on one node of the first diagram then i want a particular node of the second diagram to be selected and rest all previously selected node in the second diagram to be not selected.

Answer (score 4):

Call `Diagram.select`, ([documentation](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#select)), on the Node that you want to be the only selected Part.

You may need to call `Diagram.findNodeForData` or `Diagram.findNodeForKey` to get the Node in the Diagram corresponding to the desired data in the Model.

As always, you can search the samples and documentation for example uses.  I particularly suggest the [Local View sample](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/localView.html), which does something similar to what you might be wanting to do.